# Handle errors in method returning HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#

I have this class that I can use to make a request to different paths with different Request methods(GET, POST etc).

I just added `try` and `catch` to log errors, however I don't know how to handle the catch block? I can't return an empty HttpWebResponse. `"Not intended to be used directly from the code"`

```
private static HttpWebResponse HttpRequest(string method, string path)
{
    try
    {
        var httpWebRequest =
            (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"] + path);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = method;
        httpWebRequest.Credentials =
            new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]);
        httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

        return (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e, "HttpRequest error");
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont catch a general `Exception` - instead catch a `WebException` which might contain a `Response`. Otherwise, just rethrow the error after logging it.

```
try
{
    ... make request
}
catch (WebException webExcp) 
{
    Logger.Error(webExcp, "HttpRequest error: " + webExcp.Status);
    if (webExcp.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
        return (HttpWebResponse)webExcp.Response;            
    }
    throw;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Other exception, not a WebException, you probably want to Log an throw
    Logger.Error(ex, "HttpRequest error"); 
   throw;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead, you can return an [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx), and in a `catch (Exception ex)` return something like this:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
{
    Content = new StringContent(string.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        ex.GetType().FullName,
        ex.Message))
};
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
return response;
```

(With `ContentType` and `Content` set to suit your purposes)

Answer (score 1):

You could just re throw the error, which passes responsibility up the chain.

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.Error(e, "HttpRequest error");
    throw;
}
```

Or you could return `null`

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.Error(e, "HttpRequest error");
    return null;
}
```